# $\frac {\partial x}{\partial u} \wedge \frac {\partial x}{\partial v} \ne 0$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $x(u, v)$ be a parametrization of a surface $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. Verify that $dx_q : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is one-to-one if and only if

$\frac {\partial x}{\partial u} \wedge \frac {\partial x}{\partial v} \ne 0$

---

How can I do this problem?Can I get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$dx_q$ is a linear transformation whose image is spanned by the vectors $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u},\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}$. It is thus one to one if and only if these two vectors are linearly independent.